# Can I cancel the keyword "using"?

Tags: namespaces, using

We can cancel #def by #undef.
Can I cancel "using" or "using namespace" in the similar way?

Comment: What language are you talking about? We could guess, but why make us guess? ;-)

Comment: On what condition do you want to cancel it, at what point?

Comment: Luchian has guessed for us, but you should check that he's right.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Your best solution is not to have `using` directives in header files, and minimize (and even remove them completely) their use from source files.

If you're having troubles with namespaces, you can use `::` to go to the global `namespace`, but the cleanest way is clearing the directives.

EDIT: This applies to C++.

Comment: +1 on not using in the headers. Removing completely is probably too draconian - moving it into the narrowest scope would make more sense.